# How to know if the road is unassisted or the person is unassisted?

Tags: attachment-ambiguity

Having a text like:

> A man died of hypothermia after falling on a road, seemingly unassisted. Two homeless people found him and called for help.

I think it could be a man falling unassisted

OR

A man falling on an unassisted road

how to know which one?

the original text mention a busy road so it is implicit the man is unassisted but I contrived this example without the "busy road" information to know from English native speakers how would them reason about that.

Comment: You don't assist (that is, help) roads. Also, your first sentence is not the same as the original, because you're leaving out information -- the fact that he died, for instance!

Comment: You need to clean up your spelling.  It is really bad.

Comment: I mostly _fall over in the street_. From the pavement/sidewalk I _fall into the road_. I can do both unassisted. Do you mean your man was _unaccompanied_, or do you mean nobody came to help him after he fell?

Answer (score 3):

You understand such sentences pragmatically.  That is you let the context (and not the grammar or syntax) help you to understand the meaning.

However in your example, the meaning is unclear, for the same pragmatic reasons.

To assist means to help (somebody to do something).  It doesn't make sense to describe a road as "unassisted". Roads are static and passive, they don't get assistance.

People do get assistance, so it would make sense to say an "unassisted person".  However, you are describing the "falling" as unassisted.  That is very odd, because normally people don't get help to make them fall.

So I think you are using the wrong word.  That makes the interpretation in context nearly impossible.

Perhaps you mean that the person didn't receive any help after he fell. However this is not what you have written.

You say that you have edited from the original.  However by editing you can change the context, and by changing the context you change the meaning, or (as in this case) create a sentence that has no clear meaning.